# Play slick 3 binding/conversion object to column table

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I have a case class of `UserAccount`

```scala
case class UserAccount(Id: Option[Long], Name: String, occupation: Occupation)
```

and an object of `Occupation`

```scala
sealed trait Occupation

object Occupation {

  case object Teacher extends Occupation
  case object Student extends Occupation
  case object Others extends Occupation

}
```

I created a schema using play slick 3

```scala
class AccountSchema(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserAccount](tag, "user_account") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def name = column[String]("name")

  def occupation = column[Occupation]("occupation")

  def * = (id.?, name, occupation) <>((UserAccount.apply _).tupled, UserAccount.unapply)
}
```

When i tried to run the project. I get an error because of the column `Occupation`

How can i use the object Occupation at the slick Table column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add mapping from relational model to object model and vice versa.

```
sealed trait Occupation

object Occupation {

  implicit val occupationType = MappedColumnType.base[Occupation, String](
{ occupation => if(occupation==Teacher)  "Teacher" else if (occupation == Student) "Student" else "Others"},
{ occupation => if(occupation == "Teacher") Teacher else if (occupation == "Student") Student else Others }
)
  case object Teacher extends Occupation
  case object Student extends Occupation
  case object Others extends Occupation
}
```

Here is more details: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I'm looking for. What should I import for `MappedColumnType` ?
Edit: nvm found it, im using `import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._`.